# Arduino bot that can find a specific sound signal

Tags: arduino, audio

I am working on my senior design project. It is an Arduino controlled robot.  I am trying to figure out the best way to implement sound localization.  It seems straight forward, at least two mic's, Fourier Transform the signal, calculate the phase difference.

My problem is that I would like to be able to focus in on one particular frequency, so it isn't just trying to find the source with the biggest amplitude.  Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do something like this.  I have not used microphones ever, can someone recommend a good one?

I would like it to have a pretty decent range, like a small living room or bedroom.  I am thinking of using a very low frequency so I don't have to worry about such a high sampling rate.

I am using an Arduino Uno for anyone familiar with it.  I am doing Computer Engineering so I am pretty familiar with EE terms, but I am still learning about signal processing this semester, I know that I should use a bandpass filtering of some kind, but what would be the best way of doing it?

If you know of any examples other people have done, or schematics it would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at some papers on the topic to get some information on what works and doesn't in real life situations?

Comment: Whatever you do, you will need to calibrate the system up front. You are correct, amplitude is not the to go...

Comment: I have been doing some significant research, but I have not really found good reference material that is doing something similar to what I am trying to do.  If you find any good material please post it.

Comment: If you want to detect just a single frequency in a signal, you don't need a full blown FFT. Just compute how that signal correlates to a sine and cosine of that frequency. That's two values which give you the phase also.

Answer (score 1):

The "**Goertzel algorithm**" requires fewer resources (RAM, codespace) and less CPU cycles for a single specific frequency.

Wiki has a good set of links to delve through.

I have used Goertzel on ATMega328P and P8X32A with great results.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Late but.... a Arduino library : https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/Goertzel

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use acoustic beamforming. I would suggest posting on the DSP stackexchange but I can give you some tips.

Basic theory is to have a microphone array that separates the microphones 1/2 a wavelength apart from each other (obviously the wavelength depends on the frequency of interest.

This microphone array can be used to create a spatial filter. It is possible to then digitally scan looking for the direction with the peak signal strength. The simplest algorithm is called the delay-and-sum method. Matlab has a convenient phased array toolbox to help with the implementation.

There are still some tricks you need to worry about such as the bandwidth of the input signal. For beamforming you generally need a narrowband to compute on so you might need to implement a bandpass filter on the input acoustic signal because acoustic signals are wideband (20Hz - 20kHz).

A good resource to get started with: http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume61/number11/pxc3884758.pdf